# Recover back end database password from front end connection string

Tags: passwords, database, microsoft-access-2010

I built an MS Access database about a year ago and set separate passwords for the "front end" and "back end" components of the database. It's been a long time since I've had to access the back end directly.

I recall using a VBA macro to add the password to the connection string; I actually posted an answer regarding how to do this [here on stack overlflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607611/ms-access-cant-link-to-encrypted-backend-database/19823799#19823799)

I need to access the back end directly to make changes to the database but neither myself nor any of my users can remember the password. Funny how life works out.

Can I extract the back end password from the connection string or is it too late to do anything at this point? Would very much like to avoid the use of "password cracking" tools if possible as this is a database on a corporate network that does not allow that behavior.

(Also, not sure if this would be better suited for Stack Overflow... please move this topic if that seems more appropriate.)

Comment: If you explain the problem to your IT guys they may allow you to crack :)

Comment: Lol - I can't go into huge detail but I can promise that it will never happen. Big company... Worst case scenario we can just pull the data out of the back end from the front end and rebuild, but I was hoping there might be something easier than that.

Comment: Can you copy the database and take the copy somewhere else to play with? ;)